# ¿Porque si añado la ubicación de mi programa al PATH y luego lo ejecuto me dice que no existe en Ubuntu?

Tags: linux

En Ubuntu Server 17.04 cree el siguiente programa:

```
echo "Hola mundo" //Llamado programa
```

Esta ubicado en la siguiente ruta:

```
/home/ubuntu2017/Programa$
```

Comprobé su existencia usando `ls`:

```
/home/ubuntu2017/Programa$ ls
programa
ubuntu2017@ubuntu:~/Programa$
```

Añado su ubicacion al PATH:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/ubuntu2017/Programa
```

PATH:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/ubuntu2017/Programa
```

Trato de ejecutarlo en la ubicacion donde se creo:

```
ubuntu2017@ubuntu:~/Programa$ ./programa
Hola mundo
ubuntu2017@ubuntu:~/Programa$
```

Trato de ejecutarlo en otro lugar:

```
ubuntu2017@ubuntu:~$ ./programa
-bash: ./programa: No existe el archivo o el directorio
```

**¿Por que ocurre esto si ya agregue su ruta al PATH?**

---

**Actualización 1**

Usando ls -l

```
ubuntu2017@ubuntu:~/Programa$ ls -l
total 4
-rwxrwxrwx 1 ubuntu2017 ubuntu2017 18 jul 29 01:31 programa
ubuntu2017@ubuntu:~/Programa$
```

Comment: A ver, ejecuta este comando: `/home/ubuntu2017/Programa$ ls -l`... y actualiza tu pregunta con el resultado.

Comment: @toledano Listo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bueno, es que esto **"`./`"**  en `./programa` indica que el `programa` se encuentra en la ruta actual y aunque es relativa, es una ruta completa, por lo tanto no necesita Ubuntu usar la variable `PATH`. Pero como no existe el programa por eso ves el error. Si quieres que el sistema operativo use `PATH` **no escribas rutas completas**.

> Solo para aclarar, `./` no tiene nada que ver con permisos de ejecución, sino con rutas. Se puede leer como *"en el directorio actual"*.

Entonces si tienes dos *scripts* llamados `programa`, tales que:

1. Uno está en `ubuntu2017@ubuntu:~$` y
2. El otro está en `ubuntu2017@ubuntu:~/Programa$`

Y estás ubicado en `ubuntu2017@ubuntu:~$` al llamar a `./programa` se ejecutaría el del directorio actual.

Simplemente quita `./` y asunto solucionado.